# SetInterval isn't working in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Could you explain to me please what's wrong with my Timer component and how to fix that?
Stop and Reset buttons aren't working as I planned.
Stop button has to stop timer (it means `status=false`), but save last `runningTime` value.
Reset button has to clear both values (`status=false, runningTime=0`) but it clears timestamp's list only, and `status` and `runningTime` stay the same.

I guess something is wrong with the way I use `setInterval` function but I can't figure out what exactly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const initialState = {
  status: false,
  runningTime: 0,
  timestamps: []
};

export const Timer = () => {
  const [watchData, setWatchData] = useState(initialState);

  let timer = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [timer]);

  const getUnits = (time) => {
    const seconds = time / 1000;

    const min = Math.floor(seconds / 60).toString();
    const sec = Math.floor(seconds % 60).toString();
    const msec = (seconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(2);

    return `${min}:${sec}:${msec}`;
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    const { status } = watchData;

    if (!status) {
      const startTime = Date.now() - watchData.runningTime;
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setWatchData((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          status: true,
          runningTime: Date.now() - startTime
        }));
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
      setWatchData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, status: false }));
    }
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    clearInterval(timer.current);
    setWatchData({ ...initialState });
  };

  const handleLap = () => {
    const timestamp = getUnits(watchData.runningTime);
    console.log(timestamp);
    setWatchData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      timestamps: [...watchData.timestamps, timestamp]
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>{getUnits(watchData.runningTime)}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {watchData.status ? "Stop" : "Start"}
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={handleLap}>Lap</button>
      {watchData.timestamps.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {watchData.timestamps.map((t, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{t}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hofstadter-byczm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not reaffect the `timer` variable, however you can update the property `timer.current`, here is a correction of your code:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const { status } = watchData;
  clearInterval(timer.current);

  if (!status) {
    const startTime = Date.now() - watchData.runningTime;
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
      setWatchData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        status: true,
        runningTime: Date.now() - startTime
      }));
    });
  } else {
    setWatchData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, status: false }));
  }
}
```

You also can update the effect like this (to clear the interval when the component is unmounted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! But could you explain to me please why you set clearInterval before if statement?

Comment: I personally wouldn't remove the effect - it is meant to clear the interval in cases of unloading the component without clicking.

Here is my suggested solution - basically just fixing the original implementation by referring to timer.current instead of timer.
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hofstadter-byczm-fix-pqm66?file=/src/Timer.js

@Mrs.Smith - I highly recommend reading about how useRef works to understand why this fixes the issue :)

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: I prefer to clear the interval before recreating a new one (even if it's already cleared). It will work in your case if you put it only inside the `else` statement

Comment: @MosheJonathanGordonRadian you are right, I updated my answer

Comment: Cool - feel free to add the link to the sandbox if you want as well ;)